# file upload in PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to this directory:

[image: This Directory Screenshot]

with this code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../../assets/image/product/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$image = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
$merk = $_POST['merk'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$stock = $_POST['stock'];

if(isset($add)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO item VALUES('','$merk','$category','$color','$size','$price','$stock','$image')");
    echo "<script>window.location='item.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

but the uploaded file is not appearing in target directory

Comment: What happens? You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: this using local server. it's my school homework

Comment: do you check there is even a file to move?

Comment: see. my screenshot. the directory is null

Comment: for the file uploads you have to check $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) first. it it's not 0, refer to the manual page for the message.

Comment: okay, i will try it. please wait

Comment: at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: So what are you asking for? what do you expected and what happened?

Comment: @FuXu i trying to move my image file to my image directories, but i can't sorry my english bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element in your html file

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to find what error messages for.

add this line at the top of your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and this one, if it's your local (not live) server

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

so, you will be able to see the errors on screen

Finally, for the files upload make sure that upload folder have full permission and you have to check `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'])` first. it it's not 0, refer to the manual page for the message.

Comment: `echo $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']) ;exit;` or `print_r($_FILES);exit;` in top of the form submit page. (in your file put before this line `$target_dir = "../../assets/image/product/";`)